# Delphi 7 - How to assign ListView items into a combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using this code to assign values:

```
combobox1.Text:=form1.listview1.Selected.Caption;
```

But i'm getting this error: Cannot assign a TListItems to a TComboBox

Comment: Just as a note: You should *never* use `form1.` to reference anything inside an event handler of the form. It restricts you to a single instance of that form (the one referenced with the global variable `form1` created by the IDE). It will totally break if you ever change the name of that form or try to create more than one instance of the form at runtime.

Comment: You really should try to tell the truth when you ask a question. That code does not lead to that error message. The most important thing for you to learn right now is how to keep a clear head and marshal your thoughts. You'll get nowhere if you cannot even match a line of code to its error message.

Comment: I've told you once now about tagging questions. It seems the message did not get through. If you only tag delphi-7, you'll not get as many page views as tagging delphi delphi-7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a `ListView.Items` to a `ComboBox.Items` (as the compiler has told you, one is a `TListItems` collection and the other is a descendant of `TStrings`, and they're not type compatible). You can add the caption of a selected `ListItem` to the `ComboBox.Items`.

You need to add it to the ComboBox.Items:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(ListView1.Selected.Caption);
```

If you want to add all **selected** items, you need to use a loop:

```
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Selected;
  while Item <> nil do
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(Item.Caption);
    Item := ListView1.GetNextItem(Item, sdAll, [isSelected]);
  end;
```

If you just want to add all items from the `ListView` to the `ComboBox` (which seems pretty pointless, as they're already displayed in the `ListView`):

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(ListView1.Items[i].Caption);
end;
```

Comment: Okay Mr. Ken, but i need to add all itens from listview to combobox.

Comment: @Welisson: Then you need to start giving us that information in your questions, instead of waiting until after you've gotten answers to add it. :-) Do you need to add **all items**, or just the `Selected` items? You need to be more clear about what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry that I really have so much difficulty with programming and with the English. I need to transferr all itens (e.g combobox1.items := listview1.items) okay? Thanks.

Comment: @Welisson: OK. I've edited to provide two more code samples that demonstrate both. Please try to be more clear about what you're asking in the future, so we know what question we're trying to answer. It's difficult to hit a target that keeps moving. :-)

Comment: Okay @Ken White thanks, your solution is very good, and sorry for my confused answer.